# FadeInImage with cacheHeight

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I was wondering how could I use **FadeInImage** and cacheHeight at the same time for assetImage. There seems to be cacheHeight for `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` and `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork` but not `FadeInImage`.

The problem is I want assets images to have cachedHeight property and I can intially have the default placeholder.

```
          FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            placeholder: 'assets/default.jpg',
            image: imgPath,
            imageCacheWidth: 100,            // I can use it for network images
          ),
```

But,

```
          FadeInImage(
            placeholder: AssetImage('assets/default.jpg'),
            image: AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
            // cacheHeight property does not exists
          )
```

The image that is going to load has very high resolution, if it does not make sense to use asset image and fadein at the same time.

Comment: Image.asset('', cacheHeight: 50,); works

Comment: No, image could not give *ImageProvider* it takes *Image*

Comment: my bad, what about Image.asset('', cacheHeight: 50,).image

Comment: Okay, I ll check

Comment: Bro, u did it man.!!! It was too easy... Thanks bro...

Comment: I would recommend writing your answer!!! Thanks man.

Comment: well, we did it~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try following code:

```
Image.asset('', cacheHeight: 50,).image
```

[Mark as right answer pls~]

Comment: Haha... Thanks again bro.